# Conexão ao banco de dados no ASP.NET com EntityFramework

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework

Eu preciso migrar um sistema de um servidor pra outro. O sistema está em ASP.NET e a conexão com o banco de dados está meio estranha. Eu preciso saber como conectar ao banco de dados.

A única coisa que eu achei referente a *connection* no `Web.Config` foi: http://prntscr.com/brnfqs.

O que eu faço?

Comment: Como assim "está meio estranha"? O que está acontecendo? Clique em [edit] e dê mais detalhes...

Comment: Isto não é uma *connection string*. É a configuração do EF. A *connection string* está entre `<connectionStrings></connectionStrings>`.

Comment: Então cara, como eu faço pra conectar ao banco de dados com a configuração do EntityFramework no ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Entity Framework você precisar informa para o contexto qual é a conexão do banco, isso é feito passando para a classe base `: base("DataContext")` o nome da sua conexão como mostrado abaixo.

```
public class ProjetoModeloContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjetoModeloContext()
        : base("DataContext")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Configuração da `connectionStrings` no web config, logo abaixo do    `</appSettings>`

```
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DataContext" connectionString="Server=SEU_SERVIDOR; database=NORTHWND;User ID=SEU_USUARIO;Password=SUA_SENHA" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara, no Web.Config vai ter algo parecido com isso:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProjetoContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=IP/ENDEREÇO_DO_SERVER;Database=NOME_DO_BD;Trusted_Connection=false;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=NOME_USUARIO;Password=SENHA;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Só modificar conforme as configurações do seu novo servidor e do banco de dados(IP,nome do banco, usuario, senha).

Comment: <entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <providers>
   <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
 </entityFramework>